# Python method to convert ObjectId of MongoDB as string to timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, time

have got a JSON with `user_uuid": "6027fd7ad748412d1c1e80e7"`, would like to convert it to a timestamp in millisecond.

Any help please?

Many Thanks,

Comment: It seems to have a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch, http://www.lexev.org/en/2015/timestamp-objectid-mongodb/

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to have a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch

Indeed, that's all you need to do:

```py
>>> uuid = "6027fd7ad748412d1c1e80e7"
>>> seconds_since_unix_epoch = int(uuid[:8], base=16)
>>> seconds_since_unix_epoch
1613233530
```

Then, convert to datetime:

```py
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> dt.timedelta(seconds=seconds_since_unix_epoch) + dt.date(1970, 1, 1)
datetime.date(2021, 2, 13)
```